# Does trivial intersection of fields imply linear independence when one of them is the algebraic closure of the base field?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $F_0$, $F_1$ and $F_2$ be subfields of some large algebraically closed field $\Omega$. Suppose 
$F_0= F_1 \cap F_2$, $F_1$ is the algebraic closure of $F_0$, and $F_2$ is a perfect field. Does it then hold that $F_1$ and $F_2$ are linearly independent over $F_0$? Why? Do we need the assumption that $F_2$ is perfect? Where?